# Power BI Unable to Apply Query Update

Tags: c#, postgresql, powerbi

New to Power BI, but downloaded Power BI Desktop. I connected it to my Postgres Database and all was looking good. I am pulling data and able to start building relationships & reports.

I saw this curious bar appear though:

[image: Power BI Apply Changes Notice Bar]

I clicked it and it looked like it was connecting to the DB and pulling data again from all my tables. A the end I see an error notice with this warning:

`Failed to save modifications to the Server. Error returned: 'The base version must not be negative when impact is requested for a transaction.'.`

It let's me "Copy Details" and I see the full stack trace:

```
Error Message:

Failed to save modifications to the Server. Error returned: 'The base version must not be negative when impact is requested for a transaction.
'.

Stack Trace:

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException: Failed to save modifications to the Server. Error returned: 'The base version must not be negative when impact is requested for a transaction.
'.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model.SaveChanges(SaveOptions saveOptions)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.Relationships.RelationshipDetectionFast.Detect(HashSet`1 newTableColumnPairs, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RelationshipDetectionProgress progress)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.Relationships.RelationshipManager.AutodetectRelationships(RelationshipDetectionTypes detectionTypes, HashSet`1 newTableColumnPairs, RelationshipDetectionProgress progress)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.RelationshipLoader.<>c__DisplayClassf.<>c__DisplayClass11.<AutodetectRelationships>b__e()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.AnalysisServices.Relationships.RelationshipManagerHelper.ExecuteAndCommitChanges(IRelationshipManager manager, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Telemetry.PowerBITelemetryService.LogTimedAction(TelemetryUserActionId userActionId, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.RelationshipLoader.DetectAndImportRelationships(SynchronizationContext uiThreadContext, IAnalysisServicesLoadToken loadToken, IEnumerable`1 loadInputs, IAnalysisServicesLoadContext loadContext, Report report, IExtendedModelChangeScope modelChangeScope, List`1 newTableColumnPairs, Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.CreateRelationships(IAnalysisServicesLoadContext loadContext, IExtendedModelChangeScope modelChangeScope, List`1 newTableColumnPairs, Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.ProcessLoadInputs(IExtendedModelChangeScope modelChangeScope, Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.<>c__DisplayClass7.<PerformLoadInternal>b__5(IExtendedModelChangeScope modelChangeScope)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.AsyncModelAuthoringService.<>c__DisplayClass9.<RunExtendedModelChangeAsync>b__7(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Utilities.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnpackException(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.PerformLoadInternal(Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.PerformLoad(Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadTablesAsync>b__0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

Invocation Stack Trace:

   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendAndMarshalExceptions>b__0(Object null)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.WindowManager.ShowDialog[T](T form, IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.Ux.FloatingDialog.FloatingDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner, Nullable`1 showTimeout)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.FloatingDialog.KoLoadToReportDialog.StartEvaluationAndShowDialog(IEnumerable`1 queriesToLoad, Nullable`1 showTimeout, Boolean requireFullDataRefresh)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.FloatingDialog.KoLoadToReportDialog.TryShowDialogForQueries(Report report, IWin32Window ownerWindow, WindowsHost windowsHost, IEnumerable`1 queriesToLoad, LocalizedString title, Boolean requireFullDataRefresh)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.HtmlControls.ReportView.ReportCanvasProxyHtmlControlAsync.<LoadQueriesToReportFromInfoBar>b__6()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.WindowManager.ShowDialog[T](T form, IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Main>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)


ModelChangeStartingStackTrace
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.AsyncModelAuthoringService.RunExtendedModelChangeAsync(Action`1 extendedModelChange, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean blockUI)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.PerformLoadInternal(Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.PerformLoad(Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadTablesAsync>b__0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

**What does the error message mean?** I don't know what data failed to be written out.

**Also, what Server did it try to write to?** Did it fail to write to a local internal database of Power BI or did it try to write out to my remote connected postgres database?

Comment: Send a frown and add your question in the detail. The team are very good at responding.

Comment: @teylyn I did send a frown and they responded shortly after I posted this and said it was a known bug and they are working on a fix. I sent back the link to this question asking if they would post an answer as to what is going on. I am still interested in the internals of what Power BI is doing. Especially in regards to my Postgresql database.

Answer (score 3):

Older post I know, but I just got this error message and was able to get around it.

Searching around, I found [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/The-base-version-must-not-be-negative-when-impact-is-requested/td-p/546337) from a user named jagatho that says

> It has to do with the auto detection of relationships.
>   If I remove the column that would make sense that Power BI would predict having a relationship between tables and added a new one with the same name with null values in two PowerQuery steps, then I can load the data.After the initial load I can remove the two steps and everything works, because it only tries to detect relationships on the initial load.

While I wasn't able to find the column(s) causing the trouble, in Power BI Desktop (Version: 2.64.5285.661 64-bit (November 2018)), File | Options and settings | Options | CURRENT FILE | Data Load, unchecking "Autodetect new relationships after data is loaded" solved the problem for me.

[image]

Comment: I understood that the problem was from the relationships, but didn't know this checkbox! Thank you @Mike Hildner